# Swift Dictionary.reduce() - different number of iterations reported using full vs. short syntax

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm trying to get the hang of Swift, and am looking to understand why the following two method calls on a Dictionary, though they produce the same output, are reported as undergoing a different number of iterations by the Swift Playground.

```
var chocolates = ["Ram's Bladder Cup": 1, "Spring Surprise": 2, "Crunchy Frog": 3]

let chocolatesString = chocolates.reduce("", combine: {$0 + "\($1.0), "})
// The Playground says (4 times)

let newerChocolatesString = chocolates.reduce("") { (var sum: String, keyValue: (String, Int)) -> String in
return sum + "\(keyValue.0), "
// The Playground says (3 times)

print(chocolatesString)
print(newerChocolatesString)
// The output from both is however identical and as expected...
```

I'd be very grateful to understand this - I can see obviously that there is no difference in the result, but I would like to understand why the Playground reports a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playgrounds use the "n times" notation whenever a line of code is "visited" more than once during execution. This happens in lieu of showing a result because a line that has executed more than once — or a line that has executed more than one statement — can have more than one result.

When the closure body is on its own line, the playground reports that said line executed 3 times. When the closure body is in the same line as the `reduce` call to which it's passed, it says "4 times" because that line of code was "visited" 4 times during execution — once for the `reduce` call itself, and three more times for the closure body.

Note this happens regardless of which closure syntax you use — it's entirely a matter of where you put line breaks.

```
chocolates.reduce("", combine: {
    $0 + "\($1.0), "  // (3 times)
})

chocolates.reduce("") { (var sum: String, keyValue: (String, Int)) -> String in
    return sum + "\(keyValue.0), "  // (3 times)
}

chocolates.reduce("", combine: {$0 + "\($1.0), "})
// (4 times)

chocolates.reduce("") { (var sum: String, keyValue: (String, Int)) -> String in return sum + "\(keyValue.0), "}
// (4 times)
```

I don't have Xcode in front of me, but IIRC you'll see this even when you put multiple statements on one line with `;`. It has nothing to do with closure syntax and everything to do with line breaks vs statements:

```
let a = 1 // 1
let b = a + 1 // 2

let a = 1; let b = a + 1 // (2 times)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var chocolates = ["Ram's Bladder Cup": 1, "Spring Surprise": 2, "Crunchy Frog": 3]

let chocolatesString = chocolates.reduce("", combine: {
    $0 + "\($1.0), "        // (3 times)
})
let newerChocolatesString = chocolates.reduce("") { (var sum: String, keyValue: (String, Int)) -> String in
    return sum + "\(keyValue.0), "
    // The Playground says (3 times)
}

    print(chocolatesString)
    print(newerChocolatesString)
// The output from both is however identical and as expected...
```

.. the number doesn't reflect number of iterations, it reflects number of expression evaluation

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't say that I understand what you're referring to. Do you mind explaining what you mean by 'number of expression evaluation'?